# Generating a Sierpinski Carpet with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractals

how to produce a Sierpinski squared carpet with tikz?
I saw many Sierpinski triangles on the web, but I cannot find anything with the square. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: because it's bunch of squares that can be placed with loops?

Comment: Maybe, but I cannot do that.

Comment: I think you might be a little more eager to contribute rather than just mentioning the name and waiting for an answer. You can at least put a picture of it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Might take ages...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\newcount\sierpinskiorder
\newcommand\sierpinskicarpet[2][]{%
  \tikzset{sierpinski/.cd,#1}%
   \sierpinskiorder=#2\relax%
   \path [sierpinski/background/.try] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
   \SierpinskiCarpet}
\def\SierpinskiCarpet{{%
  \ifnum\sierpinskiorder>0\relax
    \path [sierpinski/foreground/.try] (1/3, 1/3) rectangle ++(1/3, 1/3);
    \advance\sierpinskiorder by -1\relax
    \foreach \x in {0,...,2}{\foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
      \begin{scope}[shift={(\x/3,\y/3)},scale=1/3]
         \SierpinskiCarpet
      \end{scope}
    }}
   \fi
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sierpinskicarpet[foreground/.style={fill=white},
  background/.style={top color=blue, bottom color=red}]{5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]